# Facebook OAuth Xamarin Forms Redirection

Tags: facebook, xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

[image]

I am using xamarin forms OAuth2 to signin into Facebook, Google and Twitter.

On android it works. But on iOS it screen freezes with spinning activity indicator at top right corner. Is there any one having same issue ?.

Update: Please find below code

```cs
partial void UIButton15_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    // https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
    clientId: "ID",
    scope: "",
    authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
    redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

    var ui = auth.GetUI();

    auth.Completed += FacebookAuth_Completed;

    PresentViewController(ui, true, null);
}

async void FacebookAuth_Completed(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var request = new OAuth2Request(
            "GET",
            new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,picture,cover,birthday"),
            null,
            e.Account);

        var fbResponse = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        var fbUser = JsonValue.Parse(fbResponse.GetResponseText());
        var name = fbUser["name"];
        var id = fbUser["id"];
        var picture = fbUser["picture"]["data"]["url"];
        var cover = fbUser["cover"]["source"];
    }
    DismissViewController(true, null);
}
```

On facebook developer site:

Created app using Facebook login plugin.
Added redirect URL as http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Auth are you using? Also are there any error/message showing in the log console?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No error messages on console. I am using 1.3.0. Also tried latest 1.3.2.7.

Comment: Update the post showing the code you used to authenticate with facebook

Comment: Updated code. Thanks

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but the redirect URL is a http URL. iOS doesn't allow those by default anymore, could you update it to https or implement the `NSAppTransportSecurity` key in your info.plist file.

Comment: Yes it was set to true. Thanks for comment

Comment: try to modify those lines to :
RootView.PresentViewController(auth .GetUI(), true, null);
RootView.DismissViewController(true, null);

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED :**
Below code works

PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, false);

It seems like issue happening only with latest OAuth library. Couldn't build with previous versions of OAuth due to build errors. So created Webview based login followed by Graph API Request.